# Return multiple values based in different criteria into the same query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm pulling from a database which has multiple records for the same id, and I need to pull it all into the same table output:

| ID | Type | Value | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Age | 10 |  |
| 1 | Height | 136 |  |
| 1 | Name |  | Jeff |
| 2 | Age | 12 |  |
| 2 | Height | 156 |  |
| 2 | Name |  | Ben |

And I want my output to look like this:

| ID | Name | Age | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jeff | 10 | 136 |
| 2 | Ben | 12 | 156 |

I've tried self refrencing the table, but I can't work out how to do multiple WHERE statements to return different values based on different inputs.

Thanks!

Comment: MySQL or Postgres? Please don't add tags for databases not involved

Answer (score 0):

We can use conditional aggregation here to unpivot the data:

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Name'   THEN Value2 END) AS Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Age'    THEN Value END) AS Age,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Height' THEN Value END) AS Height
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation with case when in order to built something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    ID INT,
    Type VARCHAR(255),
    Value INT,
    Value2 VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO mytable (ID, Type, Value, Value2)
VALUES (1, 'Age', 10, NULL),
       (1, 'Height', 136, NULL),
       (1, 'Name', NULL, 'Jeff'),
       (2, 'Age', 12, NULL),
       (2, 'Height', 156, NULL),
       (2, 'Name', NULL, 'Ben');

SELECT ID
      ,MAX(CASE TYPE WHEN 'Name' THEN Value2 END) AS 'Name'
      ,MAX(CASE TYPE WHEN 'Age' THEN Value END) AS 'Age'
      ,MAX(CASE TYPE WHEN 'Height' THEN Value END) AS 'Height'
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ID;
```

[image]